# Mint 11 - no screensaver with lid closed and external monitor

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, screensaver, lid

I have `gnome-power-manager` / `buttons` / `lid_ac` configured to do `nothing` when the lid is closed.  When I lock the screen, the screensaver does not come on any more.

If I set lid_ac to `blank` and leave the lid open, lock screen engages the screensaver as expected.

What do I need to do to allow me to keep the lid closed while utilizing the screensaver?